# SQL update query over two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got two tables:

```
Table Name: One
id  | status
----+--------
1   | 1
2   | 1
3   | 1

Table Name: Two
id  | model
----+--------
1   | m001
2   | m002
3   | m003
```

Let's say I want to change the status of `m001` to `0`. How can I achieve this using an SQL statement?  i.e. if model = m001, get id, go to table.one, change status to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't mentioned your `RDBMS`, try any of these:

For `MySQL`

```
UPDATE  One a
        INNER JOIN Two b
            ON a.ID = b.ID
SET     a.Status = 0
WHERE   b.model = 'm001'
```

For `MSSQL`

```
UPDATE  a
SET     a.Status = 0
FROM    One a
        INNER JOIN Two b
            ON a.ID = b.ID
WHERE   b.model = 'm001'
```

Which works on other DBMS

```
UPDATE  One 
SET     Status = 0
WHERE   ID = (  SELECT ID
                FROM two 
                WHERE model = 'm001')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   UPDATE TabelOne as a SET Status = 0
   WHERE a.id = (select id from two where model = 'm001')
```

My SQL -

```
   UPDATE TabelOne as a 
   INNER JOIN two as b ON a.id = b.id and b.model = 'm001'
   SET Status = 0
```

Comment: We don't need a sub-select do we? An inner join would be more appropriate if there is referential integrity.

Comment: OP didn't mentioned the db, so generically sub query will work on most ;) and ya joins will be faster always.